# How can I run a capistrano task twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I have a capistrano task I'd like to run twice during a deploy.

Specifically, I'd like to run a puma phased restart before I start deploying and after assets are compiled (part of capistrano-puma gem).  The reason for running the phased restart before is to reduce memory usage to the point where the new asset compilation task (which starts a rails environment) does not cause the server to go into memory swap.  We've been doing this manually, but sometimes forget.

If I add this to my deploy file:

`before 'deploy:started', "puma:phased-restart"`

Then my phased restarts are only run once and puma ends up running out of the wrong release directory.

**How can I re-enable a capistrano task and allow it to run twice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to running rake tasks twice, you can re-enable the task:

Just add this to your deploy file

```
after 'deploy:started', 'reenable_phased_restart'
task :reenable_phased_restart do
  ::Rake.application['puma:phased-restart'].reenable
end
```

Comment: Actually, since capistrano3 is based on Rake now, it's exactly the same as running rake tasks twice, as discussed here https://www.michaelrigart.be/en/blog/rake-basics.html